# Store and set all localstorage in variable

Tags: javascript, html, local-storage

I need to save all domain localStorage in variable and later set it again from variable.

I trying  save localstorage with this code:

```
for (var i = 0, len = localStorage.length; i < len; ++i) {
 objects = JSON.stringify(localStorage.getItem(localStorage.key(i)));
}
console.log(objects);
```

But it gives me a error. And how can i set all localstorage from variable? Something like this?

```
for (var i = 0, len = objects.length; i < len; i++) {
      localStorage.setItem(len, objects(i);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You could do something like this to set the items:

```
function setItem(key, value){
    if (typeof value === 'object') {
        value = JSON.stringify(value);
    }
    localStorage.setItem(key, value);
}
```

and something like this to retrieve it:

```
function getItem(key){
    if (key){
        try{
            return JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem(key));
        }
        catch(e){
            return localStorage.getItem(key);
        }
    }
}
```

`localStorage` only save strings, numbers or booleans so if your value is an object you need to **stringify** it before save it, then when you retrieve it you need to **parse** it again to an object.

**Now take this 2 functions and use them like wrappers to access the localStorage values in your loops.**

**[Update - Fixing Loops]**

**Get Data**

```
var objects = {};
for (var i = 0, len = localStorage.length; i < len; i++) {
  objects[localStorage.key(i)] = getItem(localStorage.key(i));
}
console.log(objects);
```

**Set Data**

```
for (var o in objects) {
   setItem(o, objects[o]);
}
```

Comment: Can you please help me with creating correct loops with your functions? I'm new for JS and would be very grateful to you